# how to simply concat to NSString in swift

Tags: swift, nsstring

I am looking for the simpliest way to concat 2 NSStrings together.
I am not looking for concatenating to Strings. That I am able to.
I am looking for concatenating two NSStrings without converting them to String. Is that possible ?

```
var s1:NSString="bla1";
var s2:NSString="bla2";

var s3:NSString=s1 + s2;
```

I know I could convert them to String, but I guess this is costly. I can't beleave, that there is no way to concat NSStrings.

Comment: It's not really costly. The system converts them back and forth all the time.

Comment: I am having actually a performance problem, because of doing a lot of string parsing and so on and I have the evidence that there is a big difference between NSString and String regarding performance. Thats why I like to avoid involving String.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use `NSMutableString` then and append directly into it? Most performance problems with strings are caused by the creation of new objects.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this hint. I will take a look into this. So I can directly append the string to the same object like in Java using a Stringbuffer ?

Comment: Yes. The same works with the swift `String` if you declare it as `var`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this NSString withFormat:

```
var s3: NSString = NSString(format: "%@%@", s1, s2)
```

You can also create function for operator + which works with NSStrings

```
func +(lhs: NSString, rhs: NSString) -> NSString {
    return NSString(format: "%@%@", lhs, rhs)
}
var s3: NSString = s1 + s2
```

Comment: Thanks for helping. I hope this is the easiest way. Thanks, but still don't like it much, because I can't see what is going on.